# pymongo upsert increment in subcollection

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a mongo db object which i want to create in the format of

```
{year:{month:{day:counts:{c:1}}}}

{
    "2014" : {
        "11" : {
            "19" : {
                "Counts" : {
                    "c" : 1
                }
}
}
}
}
```

its to actually be able to count some events every day , so in future i should be able to count the events on a particular day or even sum them up if i want to get counts of a couple of days.

I am using pymongo, and i think it could be done using an upsert, but how to do it on a property of a document like "Count"."C" here is something i am unable to achieve

```
postdata = {"2014":{"11":{"20"}},"date": curdate}
install_counter.update(postdata,{'$set':{},'$inc':{"2014":{"11":{"20":1}}}},true,false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do - insert some document like the above, or increment the nested `c` field? It looks like you want to increment `c`, so try

```
collection.update({ "_id" : <_id of doc> }, { "$inc" : { "2014".11.19.Counts.c" : 1 } })
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, could you articulate the question more clearly?

Comment: perfect, and that's exactly what i want, you know some telepathy man :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remove "$set" part from the query.
Second, increment works like that:

`"$inc": {"2014.11.20.Counts.c": 1}`